# Apache mod_rewrite: force www only if not in localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my htaccess to force the www in URLs:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

How do I only apply this if not on localhost? Is there some sort of if-condition I can put? Right now, I'm getting something like this: `http://www.localhost/` ...

Answer (score 69, accepted):

`RewriteCond` is already your "if-condition". Just add another one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Or use RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !127.0.0.1 as an alternative.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1 to be exact!

Comment: If IPv6 is enabled, localhost may resolve to `::1`, so you might want to add this: `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=::1`

Comment: Why can't I use space here? `!= localhost`

Answer (score 30):

I added all these:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=127.0.0.1
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=::1
```

Comment: Note that you can't use a space after `!=` otherwise you will get a 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using a port other than 80 (e.g. `localhost:8080`) you might need to add it to the regex too:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost(?::\d+)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^127\.0\.0\.1(?::\d+)?$
```