# .htaccess mod_rewrite: Force https and www, but not for local

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Thanks to the people of Stack Overflow I have the following in my htaccess to force www and https in URLs. It forks fine:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Now - for my local enviroment - I want to exclude a URL of the form "local.name.de"

According to this post
[Apache mod_rewrite: force www only if not in localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231324/apache-mod-rewrite-force-www-only-if-not-in-localhost) I added the following line:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=local #new line
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

but it does not work. I also tried this without success:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=local.name.de
```

Could you help me on this? Thanks

Comment: Add `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^local` line, above both exiting RewriteConds

Comment: Thank you very much. Now the www will not be added, but it still forces https. Adding the same line a second time before `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`does not help.

Comment: Perhaps you have 301 redirect cached in your browser, can you try from clean browser or from command line (with `curl -v http://local.name.de` for example)

Comment: Once again thank you very much. I just changed the order and than it works. I will post the working solution.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, this works:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^local
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^local
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```